# bootstrap accordian not working with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on a website using bootstrap, I've used the accordion (Collapse) JavaScript feature.

It is working with all browsers except with IE its not.

http://bonanza.mocorner.com/en/success_story/

The above URL, if accessed using FF or Chrome you can see that accordion is working fine. When using IE its not, any ideas? although I did include the following in my HTML header

```
<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Below is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <!-- CSS Styling starts here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public_assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public_assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public_assets/base.css" />
    <!-- CSS Styling ends here -->

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <!-- JS Starts here -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public_assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/en/js/common_js.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public_assets/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

    <!-- JS ends here -->


</head>
<body>
..............

        <script>
            $(".collapse").collapse();
        </script>

        <div class="collapse in">
            <div id="accordion-group" class="accordion">





                    <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#collapse-2" data-parent="#accordion-group" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
                                Checking Story (published on Sept. 30, 2012, 1:43 p.m.)

                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapse-2" style="height: 0px;">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                                <p><img src="/public_media/success_story/2012/09/30/happyFamily.jpg" class="img-rounded" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;" /> Checking Story...</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>








                    <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#collapse-1" data-parent="#accordion-group" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
                                The story of our lives (published on Sept. 30, 2012, 10:20 a.m.)

                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapse-1" style="height: 0px;">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                                <p><img src="/public_media/success_story/2012/09/30/promo_bts.jpg" class="img-rounded" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;" /> The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives The story of our lives.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>





            </div>
        </div>




        </div>
    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should try to localize the problem and paste the code here.

Comment: am not quite sure how to paste the code. Should I paste the HTML only? any ways, i will paste the HTML now and if you need further details let me know

Comment: OK, I just added the HTML code to the question :).. I hope it will help

Comment: By "localize" I meant to select the code related to the issue, not the whole website.

Comment: Oh I see, I will remove the parts that does not concern the question

Comment: ok done, i just removed the parts not related to the question. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [2.1.0 bug](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4499), which is resolved in 2.1.1 - you should update your Bootstrap files.